Snap apt package fails update, can not even reinstall after purging it
I recently ran a normal system update on my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS server.
All went well until apt tried updating the snap package. When it tried to unpack the new Snap version the following happened:
Preparing to unpack .../9-snapd_2.65.3+22.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking snapd (2.65.3+22.04) over (2.63+22.04ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up snapd (2.65.3+22.04) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine.real ...
Could not execute systemctl:  at /usr/bin/deb-systemd-invoke line 142.
snapd.failure.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
snapd.snap-repair.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.

I looked into /usr/bin/dev-systemd-invoke to see what happens at line 142:
 141   │         if (@start_units) {
 142   │             system('systemctl', '--quiet', @instance_args, $action, @start_units) == 0 or die("Could not execute systemctl: $!");
 143   │         }

Basically for some reason systemctl for installing the new config file fails for some reason if I understand correctly...
The only thing I know is that now I run Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS x86_64, and my current kernel is 5.15.0-124-fips. Yes, I am running an FIPS instance.
The interesting thing is that systemctl and otherwise Systemd works perfectly fine. I assume that for FIPS there is this bug which prevents installing the snap apt package correctly.
I added my experience to this bug report as it seemed the same. Some tasks are marked as fixed... but are they tho?
